# Error while showing dynamic form on Django

Tags: python, django

This is my form:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms


class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TumblrForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('blog_id')
        widgets = {
            'blog_id':forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

I basically want to show the user a list of forms.

This is where I instantiate it:

```
form = TumblrForm(instance=blogs_id)
```

I get an error saying:

```
Unknown field(s) (b, d, g, i, l, o, _) specified for Blog
```

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a comma after 'blog_id'

```
fields = ('blog_id',)
```

It looks like the string 'blog_id' is being interpreted as a list of chars rather than a single string specifying a field (notice now the error message contains all the characters of blog_id).

Answer (score 1):

Just change `fields = ('blog_id')` with `fields = ('blog_id',)` Append comma after `blog_id`.

The [fields attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) should be a list of field names to include in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TumblrForm(forms.ModelForm):
    blog_id = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
```

Why you have blog_id? Because basically django automatically create id (pk) in every model